# How to detect if probably counterfeit drive is SSHD (hybrid) at all

Tags: hard-drive, hybrid-storage

I bought a hard drive over the Internet, a 4TB Seagate SSHD (hybrid drive), but I have reason to believe that it is counterfeit.

1. The label says "Desktop HDD", but it is supposed to be a SSHD model and should therefore read "Desktop SSHD".
2. The model ID (ST4000DX001) and part number don't match. The printed PN (1NS164-300) is for the 2TB version.
3. The firmware specified on the label (CC41) doesn't match installed firmware (CN03).
4. Installed firmware (CN03) is for Seagate Constellation SAS-series, not for SATA hybrid drives.
5. Running a warranty check on Seagate.com says that there is no drive with the serial number printed on the label (W8E2D07P).
6. QR-code printed on label for authenticity validation does not work.
7. Manually running a authenticity validation on verify.seagate.com with printed code 26222609402 says that the drive is invalid.

I'm currently running F3 to see if reported disk size has been hacked. Should be another 12 hours to go before I have the answer.
*Edit:* F3 reports all good.

Now, is there a way for me to test if this drive indeed is a SSHD or just a plain HDD?

Comment: @computercarguy the HD in SSHD still means hard drive though. An SSHD is a hard disk with a solid state cache to improve boot speeds, it is a mixure of both SSD and HDD. It *should* look like an HDD and not an SSD.

Comment: Doesn't the manufacturer (Seagate) have diagnostic software you can check the drive with? See what it says. You've already checked with it's reported SMART data I guess, it said the firmware doesn't match the label? Did it say the drive's model?

Comment: @Xen2050: Seagate SeaTools reports an ST4000DX001 with serial no W8E2D07P and firmware CN03.

Comment: Updated my answer a little, maybe it's just a bad label from a 3rd party reseller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could remove the PCB and identify the chips.  In the example below of a different Seagate SSHD, the LSI and Samsung chips at the top are the HDD controller and DRAM memory (cache).  The eASIC and Samsung chips below them are the SSD controller and NAND flash memory.

[image]

**Edit:** Here's a Seagate 3.5" SSHD PCB.  Similar chips, except with Toshiba NAND flash.

[image]

Comment: I like this solution! But somehow I get the feeling that this would void the warranty if the drive turns out to be genuine.

Comment: @LapplandsCohan They have "warranty void" stickers on the hard drive top case, but not the PCB--they wouldn't know if you had removed it.  Besides, you've already determined that Seagate doesn't recognize its warranty.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's many other tests to try, other than manufacturer's diagnostics & SMART data, the drives usually automatically pick what to put in the faster SSD section so there's no user or OS control over it, it's essentially a "black box."

You could try reading the same data over and over, and see if the drive eventually moves it to the SSD & then starts giving insanely fast read speeds.

You'd have to watch out for the OS disk cache, and the size of the SSD section, apparently it's 8GB (see below), but I'd guess use maybe 20%-50% of the SSD size, and at least double your ram+disk cache?

If F3 reports all's good, then trying to read the same few files (it uses 1GB test files, so read 3 or 4 of them) maybe 10 times in a row should convince the drive to put that data into it's faster SSD section, and increase read speeds from HD (150MB/s?) to SSD (750MB/s?).

If it does speed up, and passes all SMART tests & seems good, then it sounds like just a bad label, maybe from a weird 3rd party reseller. Any warranty issues in the future is all I'd worry about, if whoever you bought it from will do exchanges themselves that's ok, it sounds like Seagate won't automatically (through their webpage at least).

---

You said Seagete's SeaTools reports it's a ST4000DX001, and NewEgg says that's a [Seagate Desktop SSHD ST4000DX001 4TB 64MB Cache SATA 6.0Gb/s 3.5" Solid State Hybrid Drive Bare Drive](https://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16822178379) with apparently 8GB for the "hybrid" flash section ("NAND Type / Size" of "MLC / 8GB").

Being a "Bare Drive" I wouldn't be surprised if Seagate didn't have it in their retail drive warranty somehow, and the part number could be from whatever company bought the drive from Seagate & put on their own label...

Comment: F3 reports all good. Created a loop that read the same 7 1GB test files over and over again 200 times. Speed never moved above 150 MB/s. Makes it feel like a regular HDD.